# Can I import contents of a table into a Laravel seed?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a team member who needs my whole database structure and content.

I've used a library to generate migrations for database structures (https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator).

Is a way to seed those database tables with data that I have already existing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a package like iSeed - that creates Laravel 4 migrations and seeds based upon existing database tables.

https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

Comment: Thank you. Worked very well for me.